# Blocking SkyDrive on windows 7

Tags: web, blocking, cloud-storage

I need to block access to MS Skydrive.  Its easy enough to block the application, using AppLocker or our AV program.  However it will still be available via the web.  Is SkyDrive.com and Skydrive.live.com the only URLs associated with it?  Or are there others?

Also, as far as I know, Dropbox, SugarSync, and Box.net only use "theirname.com."  Correct?

Comment: Start with blocking the installation of programs in general, picking only cloud backup programs, will lead to you to adding additional programs every day. Use firewall level filtering to handle blocking browser access to those cloud services.

Comment: thats part of the issue, these are field technicians and will be connecting to the internet via cell based tethering...  hmm  I wonder if the provider can do filtering...

Comment: Everything I described can be handled by DNA filtering and domain policy...

Comment: they have local admin, so they can bypass policy

Comment: What you want cannot be done if they have local admin.  So you will have to revoke that permission level.  Create a new user group with almost all permissions except that.